# Stop images from stacking

Tags: css, image

I've made my images purposely overlap each other vertically, but now the images have stacked on top of each other. How do I stop this from happening? Here is [my site](http://tinyurl.com/kqngj4g).

I tried adding a z-index to the images, which worked on a previous layout, but hasn't worked with this -

```
.home_post_box {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 356px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.home_post_box img {
    width: 371px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    transform: -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: And please, *please* don't format your CSS that way. Single rules per line is much easier to work with (it will also help you work out issues).

Comment: Motto, as I said in the title and in the text, I'm trying to stop the images from stacking

Comment: Josiah, now edited my css. I agree, much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is close to what you try

```
.home_post_box {
float: left;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}

.home_post_box img {
height: auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
transform: -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
outline: 1px solid transparent;
text-align: center;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
padding-left: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. so I just add float: left ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see, you should try encapsulating each row of pictures in its own `<div>` and put your `desktop-clear` or `tablet-clear` elements between those rows.

You might also use this [clearfix trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) for clearing, its a bit cleaner but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps it will be useful.